# Can initiating a goroutine (i.e. calling 'go') fail?

Tags: go, concurrency, goroutine

Is it possible to fail when executing `go f`?

Since the keyword go has no return value, how to determine whether a goroutine is successfully started during high concurrency?

For Example:

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "sync"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    var wg = &sync.WaitGroup{}
    go func() { // How do I know if there is any failure here?
        wg.Add(1)
        fmt.Println("halo world")
        wg.Done()
    }()
    time.Sleep(time.Nanosecond)
    wg.Wait()
}
```

Comment: Every goroutine run if main programme does not fail

Comment: "How do I know if there is any failure here?" Not at all. The situations in which a goroutine cannot be started are so extreme that you cannot do anything anymore. Even if there would be an indicator that this `go` failed you would not be able to react to that infomation in any sensible way.

Comment: I think so too, thank you for answering my doubts.

Answer (score 4):

The [`go`](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Go_statements) statement cannot fail (only in "extreme" circumstances like out of memory, but then a failing `go` statement would be the least of your problems).

Of course without synchronization you don't have guarantee when that goroutine is scheduled to run. Your example use of [`sync.WaitGroup`](https://golang.org/pkg/sync/#WaitGroup) therefore is incorrect, as if the goroutine is not scheduled until the `main` goroutine reaches `wg.Wait()`, it may never even start, as when the `main` goroutine ends, your program ends as well.

Instead increment the WaitGroup's counter in the main goroutine (and it's best to call `WaitGroup.Done()` deferred, so it gets called even if the goroutine would panic):

```
var wg = &sync.WaitGroup{}
wg.Add(1)
go func() {
    defer wg.Done()
    fmt.Println("halo world")
}()
wg.Wait()
```

That way you don't even need the sleep, `wg.Wait()` will block until the other goroutine calls `wg.Done()` (which will happen only when the other goroutine completed its work).

Comment: wow~,thank you for you answer. 
I read a lot of blogs and didn't find the answer, but now I understand.